# Как сделать приоритет BroadcastReceiver самым высоким на Android device?

Tags: android, android-sdk, activity

Как сделать приоритет приложения самым высоким на Android device ? То есть, чтоб например при входящем вызове данное приложение реагировало первым ( раньше чем нативные приложения ).

Comment: Спасибо большое ! Напишите в виде ответа, подниму Вашу репутацию !

Comment: "Если же речь о перехвате Broadcast , то его приоритет задается параметром android:priority в манифесте "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы установить приоритет перехвата события через `BroadcastReceiver`, в манифесте приложения нужно указать приоритет для этого события через атрибут `android:priority`:

```
<receiver
    android:name="MyReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>           
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Чем значение больше, тем приоритет выше. Документация рекомендует устанавливать это значение в пределах констант (но не включительно)  SYSTEM_LOW_PRIORITY = -1000 и SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY = 1000, то есть максимальный приоритет будет = 999, но на практике для высокого приоритета ставят максимальное значение для типа int = 2147483647, хотя в доках вроде как и предупреждают, что больше 1000 обрабатываться не будет. Нужно пробовать.

Официальная [документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) на этот счет